# Why is this forloop skipping items in the list?

Tags: python, for-loop, try-catch

When I run the code below it seems to only iterate through half of the total list of workers in the list.  It then jumps to closing the parent process.

I'm super confused why the code below isn't iterating through all the items in the list perhaps I've stared at this too long to see the obvious?  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the console out.

```
Waiting...
[u'worker-1.15579', u'worker-1.15575', u'worker-1.15577', u'worker-1.15570', u'worker-1.15573', u'worker-1.15168', u'worker-1.15170']
The terminate_pid is 15561
Process was SUCCESSFULLY closed.
Process was SUCCESSFULLY closed.
Process was SUCCESSFULLY closed.
no process found with pid 15170
Process was already closed.
Closed terminator window.
```

Below is the code,

```
            workers_to_be_restarted = [u'worker-1.14524', u'worker-1.14526', u'worker-1.14518', u'worker-1.14528', u'worker-1.14522']

            for item in workers_to_be_restarted:
                if this_machine == item.split('.')[0]:
                    if not terminate_pid:
                        try:
                            terminate_pid = psutil.Process(psutil.Process( int(item.split('.')[1]) ).ppid()).ppid()
                            print "The terminate_pid is {}".format(str(terminate_pid))
                        except Exception, e:
                            terminate_pid = None
                            print e
                            pass
                    try:
                        print "Terminating {}".format(item)
                        p = psutil.Process( int(item.split('.')[1]) )
                        p.terminate()
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print "Process was SUCCESSFULLY closed."
                        workers_to_be_restarted.remove( item )
                    except Exception, e:
                        print e
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print "Process was already closed."
                        workers_to_be_restarted.remove( item )
                        pass
            try: #THE ABOVE SEEMS TO BE EXITING HERE before looping through all the items!? NOT SURE WHY?
                if terminate_pid:
                    p = psutil.Process( terminate_pid )
                    p.terminate()
                    print "Closed terminator window."
                    worker_restart['restart'] = None
                    worker_restart['workers_to_be_restarted'] = workers_to_be_restarted
```

Comment: How did you verify that it doesn't work?

Comment: These `try` `excepts` are some pretty questionable code structure. Catching exceptions like this scares me a little bit.

Comment: @TimCastelijns -- Check above for output.

Comment: @Elizion Yes I agree -- I've literally put these in there just to see what's going on.  Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it looks like you are only iterating over a portion is because of `workers_to_be_restarted.remove( item )`. This is actually removing the *next* item in your list, not the one that you intend to remove. For instance:

```
workers_to_be_restarted = [u'worker-1.14524', u'worker-1.14526', u'worker-1.14518', u'worker-1.14528', u'worker-1.14522']
for item in workers_to_be_restarted:
    print(item)
    workers_to_be_restarted.remove(item)
```

***Output:***

```
worker-1.14524
worker-1.14518
worker-1.14522
```

As you can see, the second and fourth workers are being removed while iterating over the others. 
To fix this issue, make a *copy* of your list and iterate over it first. I would replace your current line with a full list slice assignment like this:

```
for item in workers_to_be_restarted[:]:
```

***Output:***

```
worker-1.14524
worker-1.14526
worker-1.14518
worker-1.14528
worker-1.14522
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you modify a list that you are iterating over:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for each in foo:
    if each == 2:
        foo.remove(each)

    print each


>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 4
>>> 5
```

To solve this, you can copy the list into a new one, and make removals from the copy (not the one you are iterating through):

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
bar = list(foo)

for each in foo:
    if each == 2:
        bar.remove(each)

    print each

print bar

>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
>>> 4
>>> 5
>>> [1, 3, 4, 5]
```